# ConvertFrom-String and ghost property

Tags: string, powershell, csv

I am getting the firmware information of a server and I have it in a variable `$t` but it's in the form of a string. I've (almost) successfully structured it into an object in order to export it into a CSV but there are a few kinks I need help with.

My main problem at the moment is that it seems like using `ConvertFrom-String` changes things like `4.10` to `4` or `2017/04/06` to `4/6/2017 12:00:00 AM`. Is there any way around this?

Another issue is the ghost property `P6` that shows up even though I am not explicitly asking for it. I deal with this by removing it afterwards but I wonder if I'm doing something wrong to spawn it.

```
PS C:\Users\user> $t.Output
system> Type                     Status       Version      BuildID          ReleaseDate
----                     ------       -------      -------          -----------
IMM2(Primary)            Active       4.10         TCOO32C          2017/04/06
IMM2(Backup)             Inactive     3.70         TCOO26H          2016/11/29
UEFI(Primary)            Active       2.40         TCE130J          2017/04/11
UEFI(Backup)             Inactive     2.40         TCE130J          2017/04/11
DSA                      Active       10.2         DSALA8N          2016/10/28
system> 

PS C:\Users\user> $t.Output | ConvertFrom-String -PropertyNames 'Type', 'Status', 'Version', 'Build', 'ReleaseDate' | Select-Object -Index 2,4

Type        : IMM2(Primary)
Status      : Active
Version     : 4
Build       : TCOO32C
ReleaseDate : 4/6/2017 12:00:00 AM
P6          : 

Type        : UEFI(Primary)
Status      : Active
Version     : 2
Build       : TCE130J
ReleaseDate : 4/11/2017 12:00:00 AM
P6          :
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the output of `$t.Output.GetType().FullName`?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Output of that line is `System.String[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After replacing the hindering elements from the simulated output,
`ConvertFrom-Csv` can do its job (the time still missing in your sample)

```
$toutput= @"
system> Type                     Status       Version      BuildID          ReleaseDate
----                     ------       -------      -------          -----------
IMM2(Primary)            Active       4.10         TCOO32C          2017/04/06
IMM2(Backup)             Inactive     3.70         TCOO26H          2016/11/29
UEFI(Primary)            Active       2.40         TCE130J          2017/04/11
UEFI(Backup)             Inactive     2.40         TCE130J          2017/04/11
DSA                      Active       10.2         DSALA8N          2016/10/28
system> 
"@

$toutput -replace 'system> *' -replace '(--+\s+)+' -replace '\s{2,}',',' |
    ConvertFrom-CSV | Format-Table -auto
```

---

```
Type          Status   Version BuildID ReleaseDate
----          ------   ------- ------- -----------
IMM2(Primary) Active   4.10    TCOO32C 2017/04/06
IMM2(Backup)  Inactive 3.70    TCOO26H 2016/11/29
UEFI(Primary) Active   2.40    TCE130J 2017/04/11
UEFI(Backup)  Inactive 2.40    TCE130J 2017/04/11
DSA           Active   10.2    DSALA8N 2016/10/28
```

Comment: @ImagineThat You posted a new question, but did you try this solution? If $t.ouput type is string it should work.

Answer (score 1):

This `12:00AM` and `4.10` to `4` stuff is happening because `ConvertFrom-String` is setting the type for the items, a DateTime for the date and an int for the status.

To work around this you can use the `-TemplateContent` parameter to explicitly set the types you want, in this case strings.

```
$template = @'
{Name*:IMM2(Primary)} {Status:Active} {[string]Version:4.10} {BuildID:TCOO32C} {[string]ReleaseDate:2017/04/06}
{Name*:UEFI(Primary)} {Status:Inactive} {[string]Version:10.2} {BuildID:DSALA8N} {[string]ReleaseDate:2016/10/28}
{Name*:DSA} {Status:Inactive} {[string]Version:10.2} {BuildID:DSALA8N} {[string]ReleaseDate:2016/10/28}
'@

$data | ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $template -OutVariable out_data
$out_data
```