# ConvertFrom-String with template

Tags: string, powershell

I am trying to get specific properties from a string output using a template and `ConvertFrom-String`. It works without using a template and using the `PropertyNames` flag, but version numbers like `4.10` are truncated to `4` and dates like `2017/04/11` changes to `2/7/2017 12:00:00 AM` so I tried to use a template like the following:

```
$fwTemplate = @'
system> Type                     Status       Version      BuildID          ReleaseDate
----                     ------       -------      -------          -----------
IMM2(Primary)            Active       {[string]IMMVersion*:4.10}         {IMMBuild:TCOO32C}          {[string]IMMDate:2017/04/06}
IMM2(Backup)             Inactive     3.70         TCOO26H          2016/11/29
UEFI(Primary)            Active       {[string]UEFIVersion:2.40}         {UEFIBuild:TCE130J}          {[string]UEFIDate:2017/04/11}
UEFI(Backup)             Inactive     2.40         TCE130J          2017/04/11
DSA                      Active       10.2         DSALA8N          2016/10/28
system> 
'@
```

However I get the following error:

```
ConvertFrom-String : ConvertFrom-String appears to be having trouble parsing your
data using the template you've provided. We'd love to take a look at what went
wrong, if you'd like to share the data and template used to parse it. We've saved
these files to C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\5lyfkyrm.c2v.input.txt and
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\5lyfkyrm.c2v-0.template.txt - feel free to
attach them in a mail to psdmfb@microsoft.com. We will review all submissions,
although we can't guarantee a response.
At line:1 char:23
+ $fwObj = $fw.Output | ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $fwTemplate
+                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidResult: (Microsoft.Power...yFlashExtract():ProgramNotFoundException) [ConvertFrom-String], ProgramNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ProgramNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StringManipulation.ConvertFromStringCommand
```

Am I doing something wrong in my template or is `ConvertFrom-String` buggy enough to warrant emailing logs to Microsoft for review?

Comment: Does that cmdlet support strong typing in the template?  I couldn't find online documentation.

Comment: Works just fine for me if I take the template from [Persistent13's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45701601/1630171) to your previous quesiton and replace `[string]` with `[Version]` and `[DateTime]` for the version and date fields respectively.